# Static block doesn't show up in CMS page and Im using Magento2

Tags: logging, configuration, static, magento2, block

As of now, I have tried the first method being `System => Permissions => Blocks`, which seems to not be present in **magento2**. An alternative should be `System => Configuration => Advanced (Developer)` and under `Log Settings` option, `Enable Logs`.

But I am unable to find `Log settings` section, so I need help to fix this issue of static block not showing in CMS pages without affecting the XML file.

Comment: You will have to be a little more precise. Did you create a CMS page via the backend and configured it to show the static block? Did you create a `default.xml` overriding your shop layout and inserting a static block?

Comment: I have used the admin panel(backend) to create my cms page and configured it to show the static block. No I haven't done any changes in XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, first of all make sure you're in developer mode. `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`
Next up, activate block path hints. This feature makes your website look very messy, but it's actually a super nice feature to find out how your shop is rendered.
In backend, go to `Stores => Settings => Configuration => Advanced => Developer => Debug` and set `Enable path hints` for frontend. I am not certain, wether this will show paths of static blocks, but I think it should.
Otherwise, take one of the blocks from `default.xml` and add it to your CMS page, to make sure the CMS page is correctly rendered in the first place.